# Linq Nested Projections in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In a Linq projection for an EF entity, I am able to select only properties which are required.

In the code below ex questions. Now question has navigation property as options.
I want to select only option id and option title as nested property

If I write

```
options.ToList()
```

it will work with all properties.

I want only `Options.ID` and `Options.Title` to be included

```
var query = from c in context.Sec_Questions.AsNoTracking()
            where c.IsActive == true
            select new
                   { c.ID, c.QuestionType,
                     c.Title, c.ControlName,
                     c.IsNumberOnly,
                     c.Maxlenghth,
                     options = c.Options.ToList(),
                     c.IsMultiple,
                     c.ControlID,
                     c.HelpText,
                     c.IsRequired };
var questions = query.ToList();
```

But this code doesn't work

```
var query = from c in context.Sec_Questions.AsNoTracking()
            where c.IsActive == true
            select new
                   { c.ID, c.QuestionType,
                     c.Title, c.ControlName,
                     c.IsNumberOnly,
                     c.Maxlenghth,
                     options = new { c.Options.ID, c.options.Title },
                     c.IsMultiple,
                     c.ControlID,
                     c.HelpText,
                     c.IsRequired };
 var questions = query.ToList();
```

Comment: try to use FirstOrdefault if the Options is list type you can't get property vaule directly from list with selecting specific instance

Comment: Why is options a list object?  Does it need to be?  When you have a list object you need to select only one item in the array  to get the properties.  I usually use FirstOrDefault : options = new {c.Options.FirstOrDefault().ID,c.optionsFirstOrDefault().Title},

Answer (score 4):

From this `c.Options.ToList()` I understand that `Options` is a collection. So what you should do is use `.Select` to project a new object containing just those two properties:

```
var query = from c in context.Sec_Questions
            where c.IsActive == true
            select new {
                c.ID, 
                c.QuestionType,
                c.Title, 
                c.ControlName,
                c.IsNumberOnly,
                c.Maxlenghth,
                Options = c.Options.Select(o => new { o.ID, o.Title }),
                c.IsMultiple,
                c.ControlID,
                c.HelpText,
                c.IsRequired };
```